# A div that follows another appears to alter the first div's top margin

Tags: css

I have an HTML code that can be simplified as:

```
<body>
    <div class='header'>
    </div>
    <div class='main'>
        <nav class='menu'>
            <a>a</a><a>b</a>
        </nav>
        <div class='content'>Here be dragons!</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

It uses the following CSS:

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #7effad;
}

.header
{
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;   
}

.main
{
    position: relative;
}

.main .menu
{
    background-color: white;
}

.main .menu a,
.main .menu a:visited,
.main .menu a:active
{
    display: block;
    float: left;

    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.main .menu:after
{
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;

    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.main .content
{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 21px;
    margin-right: 21px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0;

    min-height: 1500px;

    background-color: #d4b074;
}
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vwvn39zd/2/) this generates some sort of a margin between the header and the menu. However, if i remove the content tag all together this margin magically disappears.

I don't understand how it can alter the appearance, since it is a normal block that **follows** the menu.

---

Edit: The problem only occurs in Firefox, Chromium does everything just fine.

The problem goes away if i set `margin-top` for `.main .content` to 0; however if `margin-bottom` of `.main .menu` is non-zero the problem returns.

Comment: please make the question clear, what the exact problem is ?

Comment: @Muhammad "As you can see here this generates some sort of a margin between the header and the menu. However, if i remove the content tag all together this margin magically disappears." An unknown margin between the header and the menu appears. I have provided the code, provided the jsfiddle, provided the description of the problem. I don't know what else to clarify.

Comment: I cannot see any margins in your fiddle. it is working well here

Comment: there is no margin in your fiddle.

Comment: This is weird. Don't know what has happened, maybe i didn't press update.